# ember render w/ ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to get a menu working using {{render}} in ember.

Controller:

```
App.NavigationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'navSheet',
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set( 'content',  [ 
            { name: 'Sheet 1', type: 'Sheet', id: 1 },
            { name: 'Sheet 2', type: 'Sheet', id: 2 }
        ]);
    }       
});

App.NavSheetController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    getID: function() {
        return 'sheet-' + this.get( 'id' );
    }
});
```

Then I use `{{render "navigation"}}` to render using the following emblem template:

```
ul
  each controller.content
    li data-type=type! id=getID! = name
```

[UPDATE WITH OUTPUT]

With "controller.content" here, I do loop through the content. With use "each" this isn't available. However, in any case the itemController is not in the context inside the loop. The resulting HTML is:

```
<li data-type="Sheet" id="">
  <script id="metamorph-8-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Sheet 1
  <script id="metamorph-8-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></li>
<li data-type="Sheet" id="">
  <script id="metamorph-9-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>Sheet 2
  <script id="metamorph-9-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script></li>
```

Note in particular that "getID" value doesn't show up. In fact I can't seem to access the itemController at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you overwriting the content in the object controller?  The content should be each item from the array controller.

Comment: That is subcontent -- content for each subitem, as I'm trying to render a nested set of items. However, in the current version is a mess as I was trying various things. (Previously I had an ArrayController). However, the item controller doesn't seem to be available at all. Will edit to make clearer...

Comment: [now edited to remove the "subcontent" as this isn't relevant...

Comment: In the example for ArrayController, you can loop through the "controller" directly. However if I try `each controller` I get nothing. I suspect that the way `{{render}}` works might be causing my problem, but I can't seem to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a emblem, so I don't totally understand the template, but if I understand correctly you're trying to get sheetId into the li and you're using the getID function to do this.  I'm going to guess that Emblem will convert it into this template

```
<li {{bind-attr data-type=type dataid=getID}}>
```

But it also looks like you're doing `getID!=name` or something like that.  That kind of logic wouldn't work in handlebars.

Now getID won't run because it needs to be a computed property

```
App.NavSheetController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    getID: function() {
        return 'sheet-' + this.get( 'id' );
    }.property('id')
});
```

Comment: The "getID!" syntax comes from the emblem doc: http://emblemjs.com/syntax/#html-attributes ... it should convert to `id={{unbound foo}}` Emblem says "make sure to use unbound" -- I'm not sure why. But the main point is that NavSheet controller is not present -- even if I put in a static attribute, it is not available.